# While loop doesn't work fine if I multiply current_savings with a number lower than 1 inside the loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am encountering an infinite while loop when I type in the following code. The problem only occurs if I multiply current_savings with a number lower than 1. 099999 doesn't give the error, but 0.999 does. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried multiplying current_savings with any floating point number above 1 and the code works fine.

```py
total_cost = float(input('enter cost of your dream house: '))
annual_salary = float(input('enter annual salary: '))
portion_saved = float(input('enter percentage of monthly salary to be saved in decimals: '))
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
saved_portion = monthly_salary*portion_saved
portion_down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
months = 0
current_savings = 0.0

while (portion_down_payment > current_savings):
    current_savings = (current_savings*0.04)/12 + saved_portion
    months = months + 1  

print(months)
```

I expected to program to print the number of months as expected, but the loop doesn't terminate for some reason.

Comment: Add `print` of `current_savings` inside the loop, after you update it, and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are calculating your current_savings, you are not including the savings you already have:

```
current_savings = (current_savings*0.04)/12 + saved_portion
```

should be

```
current_savings = current_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12 + saved_portion
```

This gives new code:

```
total_cost = float(input('enter cost of your dream house: '))
annual_salary = float(input('enter annual salary: '))
portion_saved = float(input('enter percentage of monthly salary to be saved in decimals: '))
monthly_salary = annual_salary/12
saved_portion = monthly_salary*portion_saved
portion_down_payment = 0.25*total_cost
months = 0
current_savings = 0.0

while (portion_down_payment > current_savings):
    old_current = current_savings
    current_savings = current_savings + (current_savings*0.04)/12 + saved_portion
    months = months + 1  

print(months)
```

Printing out months and current_savings within the while loop allowed me to see that the current_savings stopped changing after a point.